Reduce CPU usage for cargo run
During cargo run, rustc by default takes up all CPU resources. Is it possible to limit CPU usage? For example, cpulimit -l 40 works for cargo, but rustc processes still use 100% of the CPU.

Fedora release 40 (Forty): 6.9.7-200.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP
PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)
cargo 1.79.0 (ffa9cf99a 2024-06-03)
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged -rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)

UPD: cargo build -j x or CARGO_BUILD_JOBS=x this helped.

you've not mentioned the OS you are working with,the hardware etc - ie its too vague. take a look at taskset (linux) and see if that helps. If a program takes 100% its typically because there's 100% available ...

It is possible that this is already provided for and can be done in the Rust configuration. OS Linux (any), made an updates.

@ArtemBaranov can you try cpulimit -m -l 40?

yes - it's works for cargo, but not for rustc PID, also under /sys/fs/cgroup/ and I think I'll try edit: ~/.cargo/env

do you want something like cargo build -j x or CARGO_BUILD_JOBS=x?

Something like systemd-run --scope --user --property CPUQuota=50% cargo run maybe?

You can also look at reducing the codegen-units to directly target rustc

Thank you, @hellow, this works. I will look at the documentation more carefully.

@chesedo Reducing the codegen units will increase build time and CPU usage.

@ChayimFriedman I was thinking of reducing the codegen units to be less than the number of cores on the system. This will result in rustc using a portion of the CPU as far as I know. So this will increase the build time, but not the CPU usage.

question was reducing cpu usage during cargo run.
-j 1 does only work for cargo build.
so the combined answer of all those helpful comments would be something like this:
CARGO_BUILD_JOBS=1 systemd-run --scope --user --property CPUQuota=50% cargo run
sidenote:
my problem was memory usage slowing the process down. to reduce the memory use:
CARGO_BUILD_JOBS=1 systemd-run --scope --user --property CPUQuota=50% --property MemoryMax=500M --property MemorySwapMax=0
